# How to add a new entry to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this json file:

```
[{"industry": "car", "price": 100.0, "earnings": 10.0, "name": "Volvo"}, 
{"industry": "car", "price": 280.0, "earnings": 11.0, "name": "Audi"}, 
{"industry": "car", "price": 190.0, "earnings": 7.0, "name": "Ferrari"}, 
{"industry": "Phone", "price": 90.0, "earnings": 2.0, "name": "Nokia"}, 
{"industry": "Phone", "price": 200.0, "earnings": 14.0, "name": "Samsung"}, 
{"industry": "Phone", "price": 40.0, "earnings": 7.0, "name": "Apple"}]
```

I printed the contents of the object using the method print. I calculated the price to earnings ratio (price/earnings) for each firm

This is my code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('firm_list.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
pprint(data)
for item in data:
    pe= item['price']/item['earnings']
    print(pe)
data.update['price to earnings ratio'] = pe
```

I want to add price/earnings to the dictionary, but it doesn't work. Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `item['price to earnings ratio'] = pe` needs to be part of the loop

Comment: Just add a new entry to each `item` **in your loop** as such: `item['price to earnings ratio'] = pe`

Answer (score 0):

Put the adding operation inside the loop

```
import json
from pprint import pprint


with open('firm_list.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
pprint(data)
for item in data:
    pe= item['price']/item['earnings']
    print(pe)
    item['price to earnings ratio'] = pe
```

Comment: your code will always store the ratio of last item in the collection the data should be replaced by item

Comment: By `data['price to earnings ratio'] = pe` did you mean `item['price to earnings ratio'] = pe`?

Comment: Yes, thanks @MSH , just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('firm_list.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
    
pprint(data)
for item in data:
    pe = item['price'] / item['earnings']
    item['price to earnings ratio'] = pe
    print(pe)

pprint(data)
```

Answer (score -4):

Instead of data.update you just have to use data['price']='new value'

Comment: Did you test the line you wrote?

Comment: Item['price']=200